# Converting Json object to Java object

Tags: java, json

Value in the json file is 75.38 and i whrite a code to parse that value in eclipse:

```
 double legacyPremium = (double) object.get("legacyPremium");
```

And i get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Double at com.domain.project.Class.main(Class.java:56)
```

Json file is :

```
{  
    "elementaryProductId":1,
    "bonusMalus":5,
    "deductible":100,
    "comprehensive":1,
    "partial":0,
    "legacyPremium":75.38,
    "product":{  
        "productId":2,
        "garage":"true",
        "constructionYear":2005,
        "region":"East",
        "dateOfBirthYoungest":"1999-06-22",
        "objectValue":30000,
        "type":"Car",
        "insuredObject":{  
            "name":"Car",
            "ownersName":"Jelena",
            "mileage":300000,
            "engineCapacity":210
        },
        "salesProduct":{  
            "salesProductId":3,
            "currency":"EUR",
            "contractStart":"2013-01-01",
            "contractEnd":"2014-01-01"
        },
        "productType":"Car"
    }
},
```

Does anybody know what is the problem?

Comment: _and i whrite a code to parse that value in eclipse_ Show us that and show us your JSON.

Comment: Long v. Double appears to be the problem.

Comment: I can't find the `x`

Comment: it's legasyPremium varible

Comment: How do you parse your JSON?

Comment: Without your code (more than the one line), you do not have a valid question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
double x = Double.valueOf(object.get("x").toString());
```

instead of

```
double x = (double) object.get("x");
```

That will free you from casting problems. Take into consideration that the string must be parceable to a Double type.

Comment: Error: The method valueOf(String) in the type Double is not applicable for the arguments (Object)

Comment: Oh, excuse me. Updated the answer, should add .toString() for the object

Answer (score 0):

I would reccommend using the [Google GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) instead of Google json-simple if you are allowed to choose. With that library you can create a class that looks like what you want your json to represent and read it and convert it into an object in two lines of code. I've given an example below:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        //Read file into a String
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("file.json")));
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while((line= reader.readLine()) != null){
            builder.append(line);
        }
        reader.close();
        String jsonAsString = builder.toString();

        //Convert String into an MyClass Object
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        MyClass[] myClass = gson.fromJson(jsonAsString, MyClass[].class);//If your json outermost element is an array use this.


        System.out.println("elementaryProductId = " + myClass[0].elementaryProductId);
        System.out.println("productId = " + myClass[0].product.productId);
    }

    public class MyClass {
        public int elementaryProductId;
        public int bonusMalus;
        public int deductible;
        public int partial;
        public double legacyPremium;
        public Product product;
    }

    public class Product {
        public int productId;
        public boolean garage;
        public int constructionYear;
        public String region;
        public String dateOfBirthYoungest;
        public InsuredObject insuredObject;
        public SalesProduct salesProduct;
    }

    public class InsuredObject {

    }

    public class SalesProduct{

    }
}
```

Note the fields don't have to be public!
This is referred to as *deserializing*.